# If I install 32 bit Android Studio in 64 bit system will it work properly?

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, installation

If I install 32 bit Android Studio in 64 bit Windows system, will it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is true in general for almost all programs -- the 32-bit version will work on a 64-bit system. A 64-bit system can be seen as a "more powerful" version of a 32-bit system, which has limitations (e.g., maximum amount of RAM) that a 64-bit system doesn't (at least not to the same degree).